# PKCS11 Python FindObjects in available slots

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, pkcs#11

I wrote a script in python that gets info from a Cryptoki library. From there I can make (only)LowLevel API calls such as:

1. `C_getInfo`
2. `C_GetSlotList`
3. `C_SlotInfo`
4. `C_OpenSession`
5. `C_GetTokenInfo`
6. `C_Logout`
7. `C_CloseSession`
8. `C_Initialize`

Here's a few examples on their implementation

```
a.C_Initialize()
print("C_GetInfo:", hex(a.C_GetInfo(info)))
print("Library manufacturerID:", info.GetManufacturerID())
del info

print("C_GetSlotList(NULL): " + hex(a.C_GetSlotList(0, slotList)))
print("\tAvailable Slots: " + str(len(slotList)))

for x in range(len(slotList)):
    print("\tC_SlotInfo(): " + hex(a.C_GetSlotInfo(slotList[x], slotInfo)))
    print("\t\tSlot N." + str(x) + ": ID=" + str(slotList[x]) + ", name='" + slotInfo.GetSlotDescription() + "'")
    print("\tC_OpenSession(): " + hex(a.C_OpenSession(slotList[x], CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION, session)))
    print("\t\tSession:" + str(session))
    #print("\tMechList:" + hex(a.C_GetMechanismList(0, slotList[x])))
    print("\tC_GetTokenInfo(): " + hex(a.C_GetTokenInfo(slotList[x], tokenInfo)))
    print("\t\tTokenInfo: Label=" + tokenInfo.GetLabel() + ", ManufacturerID=" + tokenInfo.GetManufacturerID())
    print("\t\tTokenInfo: flags=" + hex(tokenInfo.flags) + ", Model=" + tokenInfo.GetModel())

    print("\tC_Login(): " + hex(a.C_Login(session, CKU_USER, pin)))
    print("\t\tSessionInfo: state=" + hex(sessionInfo.state) + ", flags=" + hex(sessionInfo.flags))
```

**QUESTION**

I can't seem to figure out what api call is needed to find objects in the slot list.. i have something like `print("Finding objects: " + hex(a.C_FindObjects(slotList[x], CKA_CLASS, CKO_CERTIFICATE)))`

I'm not sure what arguments to pass or if it's structured the right way. 
Im using this documentation [LowLevel API pkcs11](http://pkcs11wrap.sourceforge.net/api/)

Ultimately I'm trying to extract the specific omnikey smart card token.. use its private key and cert to sign and verify data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SearchResult = PyKCS11.LowLevel.ckobjlist(10)
SearchTemplate = PyKCS11.LowLevel.ckattrlist(0)
print "C_FindObjectsInit: " + hex(a.C_FindObjectsInit(session,SearchTemplate))
print "C_FindObjects: " + hex(a.C_FindObjects(session, SearchResult))
print "C_FindObjectsFinal: " + hex(a.C_FindObjectsFinal(session))
```

First you have to make a result variable and use it to search the object list. I passed 10 in, as I knew there were only a handful of objects and tokens within the list. You can construct a template variable that searches each object for specific attributes, such if it is Private, Modifiable, Key Type, Encrypt, etc. Then you have to make `(a.C_FindObjectsInit(session,SearchTemplate))` call to initialize the search in the session by template specifications. Working with the LowLevel API can be confusing, there is virtually no documentation. Hope this helps.